# why HashMap<String, Object> not accept HashMap<String, List> instance?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I am new in java generics and facing following issues.
I have have method like,

```
private static void fillDescriptiveData(HashMap<String, Object> output, String attributeMapping) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> outputInEntry : output.entrySet()) {
        String outputKey = outputInEntry.getKey();
        String outputValue = outputInEntry.getValue().toString();
        outputValue = getDescriptiveDataForOutput(outputKey, outputValue, attributeMapping);
        outputInEntry.setValue(outputValue);
    }
}
```

Now if I call API as below way

```
HashMap<String, Object> ObjectMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
HashMap<String, List> listMap = new HashMap<String, List>();
```

- `fillDescriptiveData(ObjectMap,"here");`
  this one working fine.
- `fillDescriptiveData(listMap,"here");`
  this call gives error

> The method fillDescriptiveData(HashMap, String) in the type CustomAttribute is not applicable for the arguments (HashMap, String)`

why ?

In row to solve this issue I encounter with one more issue,

```
private static void fillDescriptiveData(HashMap<String, ? extends Object> output, String attributeMapping) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, ? extends Object> outputInEntry : output.entrySet()) {
        String outputKey = outputInEntry.getKey();
        String outputValue = outputInEntry.getValue().toString();
        outputValue = getDescriptiveDataForOutput(outputKey, outputValue, attributeMapping);
        outputInEntry.setValue(outputValue); /* Error comes at this line */
    }
}

HashMap<String, ? extends Object> ObjectMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
HashMap<String, List> listMap = new HashMap<String, List>();
fillDescriptiveData(ObjectMap,"here");
fillDescriptiveData(listMap,"here");
```

error at line  -   `outputInEntry.setValue(outputValue);`

> The method setValue(capture#4-of ? extends Object) in the type
>   Map.Entry is not applicable for
>   the arguments (String)

why ?

What is the best way to avoid this issues ?

Comment: Your second "Why?" asks "Why can't I put a String as a value in a `Map<String, List>` and the answer is "because the static type system is doing its job".

Comment: what you are trying to do is clearly bad anyway, your method `fillDescriptiveData` convert your `HashMap<String, Whatever>` to a `HashMap<String, String>` which is clearly a violation, don't use generics then, simply use raw type if you want to convert a tomato into a carrot and put the result into the same collection

Comment: How about something like `Map<String, String> getDescriptiveData(HashMap<String, ? extends Object> output, String attributeMapping) {...}`? - Also, your question's title is misleading; you may want to edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the case when you could use type variables:

```
private static <T> void  fillDescriptiveData(Map<String, T> output,String attributeMapping)
{
    for(Map.Entry<String, T> outputInEntry : output.entrySet())
    {
        String outputKey = outputInEntry.getKey();
        String outputValue = outputInEntry.getValue().toString();
        outputValue = getDescriptiveDataForOutput(outputKey, outputValue, attributeMapping);
        outputInEntry.setValue((T) outputValue);
    }
}
```

More specifically, your second type-parameter in the map is unbounded. `Object` will not work here as it is specific class. `? extends Object` is somewhat nonsense.
Just `HashMap<String, ?>` would work until you will just read the map, but you will not be able to put something here. So only one way - using type variable.

**EDIT**: One more thing: please, use interfaces where it's possible. So here instead of `HashMap<String, T>` better use `Map<String, T>`. It isn't a mistake, just good and proper style of code.

Comment: Apparently you expect the `String outputValue` to be castable into an arbitrary `T`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I agree, this is quite strange, I didn't noticed that. But it will work, because in runtime you can put any values into the Map :)

Comment: The method signature that makes sense is `Map<String, ? super T> map, T value)`, but this doesn't seem to be what OP is going for. He seems to be going for something quite ill-conceived.

Comment: "`? extends Object` is somewhat nonsense" not really it is an unknown object type, it is equivalent to `?`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Actually it should be just `T outputValue = outputInEntry.getValue();`

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Nope, `? extends Object` is nonsense because it is equal to just `?`

Comment: That won't help if you inspect the next line, which reassigns `outputValue` with a descriptive string.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes, I've noticed. Well at least this code will work, and this map can be read after that in order to obtain string values

Comment: We call this a pyrrhic victory :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Ahaha, yes, exactly. But I tend to consider this question in more theoretical layer as question about proper usage of type variables, rather than delve what does this particular method do :)

Answer (score 1):

The error with this line:

```
outputInEntry.setValue(outputValue);
```

Is that you're always putting a string into the entry. This will only work if the entry is of type `? super String`, or exactly `String`. So it will not work for a `Map<String, Object>` or `Map<String, List>`.

It seems like you just want to map each value to a string. You can do it, but to be type safe, you need to create a new `Map<String, String>`. Since you're always mapping to a `String`.

If you for instance pass in a `Map<String, List<?>>` and (unsafely) replace all the values with strings. Someone could still keep using the `Map<String, List<?>>` that was passed into the function, but it now contains strings as values instead of lists. When they try to retrieve a `List` from it they get a class cast exception.

Something like this:

```
private static Map<String, String> fillDescriptiveData(HashMap<String, ?> input,
        String attributeMapping) {        
    Map<String, String> output = new HashMap<>();

    for(Entry<String, ?> e : input.entrySet()) {
            String outputKey = e.getKey();
            String outputValue = e.getValue().toString();
            outputValue
                = getDescriptiveDataForOutput(outputKey, outputValue, attributeMapping);
            output.put(outputKey, outputValue);
    }
    return output;
}
```

```
Map<String, String> r1 = fillDescriptiveData(ObjectMap, "here");
Map<String, String> r2 = fillDescriptiveData(listMap, "here");
```

Comment: This statement "This will only work" is not accurate. As I told in my answer it will work with type variable. Actual mismatch of types isn't critical problem as in runtime map can hold values of any types

Comment: @Andremoniy Of course, maybe I should have added "properly" or "in a type safe manner".